# Eventfinda API understanding

Tags: python

Not sure if anyone plays with this API before, but would like to seek your help on understanding something. URL as below :

https://www.eventfinda.co.nz/api/v2/end-points

http://api.eventfinda.co.nz/v2/events.json?rows=10&offset=10

There's a thing call **offset** in the API as per description below

> Specifies an offset into the search results. Combined with the rows parameter, this will let you return any subset of the full results. This will allow you to page through results.

```
/events.xml?rows=10&offset=0
/events.xml?rows=10&offset=10
/events.xml?rows=10&offset=20
```

Can anyone explain to me what's this about? I have been cracking it for days and yet I don't understand anything.

EDIT , code as below :

```
def download(offset):
 url = 'http://api.eventfinda.co.nz/v2/locations.json?rows=10&offset=%d'%(offset)
 username = 'test';
 password = 'test123';
 request = urllib2.Request(url)
 base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
 request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)

 result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
 data = json.load(result)

  with open("./data/locations.json", "a") as fd:
    fd.write(json.dumps(data) + "\n")
 fd.close()

def loop_offset():
 # total number is 23234
 for offset in range(0, 23234, 10):
     print(offset)
     download(offset)

loop_offset()
```

Comment: it's pagination. sometimes results are too large to return all at once so you need to return them bit by bit, by offsetting rows from your result you can ensure you don't return the same data twice, and this isn't specific to APIs either

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, how many offset do i need to set then? for example the database has 1000 count of events, each query at most returns 20 rows of events, what value of offset should i set then?

Comment: so you'll need 1000/20 queries and each one increments by 20, make sense?

Comment: so if i create a for loop to loop through these 1000 rows, does it make sense if my loop is like this? : `for offset in range(0,1000,20): print(data)`

Comment: I don't know how you're making the call, also that loop won't do anything except print the same data 50 times

Comment: I have added the code under edit, i was thinking to run it that way